# Isomorphism and partially ordered sets

Tags: functions, order-theory

Set $A$ and $B$ partially ordered sets, let $f: A \to B$ an isomorphism. Prove that:

If $C$ is a connected subset of $A$, then  $ f[C] $ is a connected subset of $B$.

Definition connected subset: a subset $C$ of partially ordered set is connected if satisfies the next condition

If $a,b \in C $ and $a \leq x\leq b$, then $x \in C$

Now, my problem is that I don't know where I start, I understand that is a direct proof $p \Rightarrow q$. I can identify my hypothesis. I was thinking this form but I'm not sure let $a,b \in f[C]$ and suppose that $a \leq x \leq b$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow$$

I really appreciate that someone can help me with the detailed explanation to be able to identify where I should start the proof

Answer (score 1):

Hints:  You start with elements $a,b\in f(C)$ and assume there is some $x$ such that $a\leq x\leq b$.   Now use that $f$ is an isomorphism,  which means it is a bijection, so you can find preimages of each element.  Then recall that the isomorphism preserves ordering which should let you use the connectivity of C.  Finally push back forward into f(C)

Comment: let $a,b \in f(C) $ and suppose that  $a\leq x \leq b$  $ \exists _w,z \in C  f(w)=a \wedge f(z)=b $ and $a \leq x \leq b$  and we know is a isomorphism $x \leq y$ then $f(x) \leq f(y) $ what do you think? @Alan